# python tic tac toe problems

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

I am new to coding and has recently started learning python. My first challenge is to build a tic tac toe game. Below are my codes for the game, everything worked fine except that when I want to restart the game or end the game, the loop won't break or the game cannot start.Could anyone figure out whats wrong with my codes. thank you!

```
Matrix = [[' ' for i in range(3)]for j in range(3)]
for i in Matrix:
    print(i)  #this is the 3x3 board

def check_done(value): #this is to check if the player has won the game
    for a in range(0,3):
       if Matrix[0][a]==Matrix[1][a]==Matrix[2][a]==value\
       or Matrix[a][0]==Matrix[a][1]==Matrix[a][2]==value:
            print ('won')
            return True
        #when the vertical column or horizontal row is equal, the     
        player won the game

       if Matrix[0][0]==Matrix[1][1]==Matrix[2][2]==value\
       or Matrix[2][0]==Matrix[1][1]==Matrix[0][2]==value:
          print('won')
          return True
       #when the diagonal rows are equal, the player won the game

       if ' ' not in Matrix[0] and ' ' not in Matrix[1] and ' ' not in     
       Matrix[2]:
            print('draw')
            return True
        #when every grid is filled in the board and no win criteria is  
         fulfilled, it is a draw
    return False

 def replay():  #this is to determine if the player wants to restart or   
                 end the game
     command =input('Enter r to restart, or e to end game: ')
     while True: 
     if command == 'r':
        player1_input()

     if command == 'e':
            return
            break

     else:
       print('Invalid command.')


def player1_input(): #this is an input function to allow players to         
                      position their next move
    print('Player 1 insert your name here')
    name1=input()
    print('player 2 insert your name here')
    name2=input()
    while True:
        inputValid = False
        while inputValid == False:
        print(name1,'please place x coordinates')
        xinput=int(input())
        print(name1,'please place y coordinates')
        yinput=int(input())
        if yinput >= 0 & yinput <= 2 & xinput >=0 & xinput <= 2: 
            if Matrix[yinput][xinput] == ' ':
                Matrix[yinput][xinput] = 'X'
                for i in Matrix:
                    print(i)
                if check_done('X'):
                    print(name1,'won')
                    replay()
                inputValid = True

    inputValid = False
    while inputValid == False:
        print(name2,'please place x coordinates')
        xinput=int(input())
        print(name2,'please place y coordinates')
        yinput=int(input())
        if yinput >= 0 & yinput <= 2 & xinput >=0 & xinput <= 2:
            if Matrix[yinput][xinput] == ' ':
                Matrix[yinput][xinput] = 'O'
                for i in Matrix:
                    print(i)
                if check_done('O'):
                    print(name2,'won')
                    replay()
                inputValid = True

 return True
```

Comment: Please can you fix your indentation so that it's an accurate representation of what you're looking at? Currently this definitely can't run. Also, are you able to reduce this down to a smaller code base? I think there's quite a bit of code you can cut out without removing the issue itself.

Comment: Your second `while` loop is infinite...

Comment: Is your game asking for input again when you enter 'r' when asked for restart?

Comment: Sorry about it. I have added some comments and resolved the indentation problems. I am not sure how to cut down the codes yet though @roganjosh

Comment: @mangoHero1  I have a break in the while loop but seems like it is not working. In addition, I also have a break in the replay function but it is not breaking the infinite loop too.

Comment: @Maomaozii except you don't. `command` is defined _before_ you enter the `while True:` loop and is _never_ calculated again. So, whatever the command is when you first enter it, that's what the command is for all eternity. It can never change. You need to move the `input` inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop for the main gameplay is running infinite.
To solve that, you can use a `continue_game` flag.
A simple example:

```
def player1_input():
    # rest of the code

    continue_game = True
    while continue_game:
        # logic for the game

        continue_game = replay()

def replay():
    # Returns true or false on user input.

    while True:
        command = raw_input('...')
        if command == 'r':
            return True

        elif command == 'e':
            return False

        else:
            print ('Invalid command')
```

The method `replay` can return a boolean as approriate based on user input.

Further, note that you have to re-initialize the matrix with empty values, if the game is supposed to be restarted.

Comment: thank you so much, I think this seems to be the problem. I will work on it based on the suggestion you gave and let you know again.

Comment: I am having some problems re-initialize the matrix, do you mind sharing some pointer on how to clear the board? thank you!

Comment: You can reinitialize as you initialized. Since `Matrix` is global, add a line in the method `player1_input` - `global Matrix` and then, write after the success `replay` call - `Matrix = [[' ' for i in range(3)]for j in range(3)]`

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to read the code as it is posted. But it seems to me that your while True is an infinite cycle. I dont see any break that allows you to exit the while

Comment: I think you're correct. You should elaborate on why this is i.e. `command` cannot be updated once you enter the `while` loop.

Comment: I have breaks at the end of the while loop but it seems to be not working at all, I also have a break in the replay function that doesn't work too